# 404s when interacting with Google Sheets REST API, 200s with Google API Explorer

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to interact with the Google Sheets API and running into an inexplicable problem that I'm finally reaching out to see how anyone else may have tackled it. Put simply, I can use the in-page API Explorer tool with only the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` OAuth2 scope at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get to query my spreadsheet (just the spreadsheet ID, leaving all other fields to empty defaults) and I'll see the 200 with the response in the bottom as expected.

Of course, I can't re-use the same access token that tool uses, but if provision an access code for the same user for my own app (same scope), and make the same GET request to `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<spreadsheetId>` in Postman (again, no other fields populated), substituting the access token into the Authentication header with `Bearer <accessToken>`, I get a 404.

I know the file is there - I've triple checked that I'm using the same spreadsheet ID across either request and I'm consistently getting a 404 (not a 401 or 403) indicating that my access token does authenticate.

I've tried broadening my OAuth2 scopes to include the full range listed on the API Explorer:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly

Of course, I don't want to have to use all those scopes for my purposes - I'd like to use the most narrow scope possible, but I also wanted to rule out that it wasn't failing to work for some scoping scenario. No difference - still a 404 every time I make the request in Postman. I've tried issuing multiple access tokens now, using accounts.google.com to invalidate the tokens for my app between re-issuances, but to no avail.

To be clear, the Google Sheets API has been enabled for my app.

In hopes that someone else has experienced the same inability to query Google's v4 REST API despite using valid access tokens, could you share how you managed to do it?

I appreciate it!

## Update:

So I've been playing around with the OAuth 2.0 Playground shared in the comments and found that the authorization endpoint I was using was identical, but the token endpoint differed. This doesn't seem to matter since I used the custom option to use the alternate endpoint and the Playground was still able to work without issue just like the API Explorer.

Using the custom entries, I also entered my own app's client ID and client secret (after registering the playground redirect URI), minimizing the differences between what I'm doing in Postman and in the various Google tools. Again, my GET request to the spreadsheet works without issue.

Just to be clear, here's what I've been doing in the Playground:

1. In Step 1, I've specified the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` scope to authorize. I click the Authorize APIs button and log in with the user account.
2. It returns with the authorization code, so I exchange that code for the tokens via a POST to the token endpoint.
3. I then make a GET request to `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<spreadsheetId>` with no additional headers and it works without issue - 200 OK and all the data I'm expecting to see.

Here my approach in Postman:

1. Make a GET request to:
   `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://<myDomain>/oauthResp&client_id=<appClientId>&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly&state=abc123`

Receive a response similar to the following in my browser on the redirect (since the domain intentionally 404s).
https:///oauthResp?state=abc123&code=zyx098&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly

2. Make a POST request to: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` with a body of:

```
client_id=<appClientId>
client_secret=<appClientSecret>
redirect_uri=https://<myDomain>/oauthResp
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Receive a response similar to:

```
{
    "access_token": "abc123",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "refresh_token": "zyx098",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

3. Make a GET request to `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<spreadsheetId>` with a 'Content-Type' header of `application/json` and an 'Authorization' header of `Bearer abc123` (per the access token above).

Unlike the API Explorer and the OAuth 2.0 Playground, this yields a 404 - exactly the issue I've been experiencing for no obvious reason.

Further, if I simply take the fresh access token from the Playground and drop that into Postman, I get the same 404.

Any other ideas?

Comment: How are you exactly doing this: _but if provision an access code for the same user for my own app_? Have you tried using Google's [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) specifying the scope as _https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly_ and using the generated token in your app? If not, please do and share the outcome you get.

Comment: I'll have to play around with the OAuth Playground - never noticed that before. I tried my path through it and it successfully pulled the content from Sheets as well, so not sure where I'm going astray (as my process seems identical at first glance). I'll update my question later this evening with a contrast between the two.

Comment: @YancyMelany Added an update with my experience with the OAuth Playground - thanks for pointing that out (really handy tool)

Comment: is the owner of the spreadsheet a Gmail.com account or a Google Workpsace one? Also, was the client ID you add in Postman generated with the same account that owns the spreadsheet?

Comment: The owner is a gmail.com account, but the app is registered on a workspace (public, testing). Oddly, this issue only seems to affect access tokens for both Google Sheets and Google Docs as I was able to add the bigquery.insertdata scope to the OAuth2 request pipeline and send data into that without issue earlier today. Still can't see the spreadsheet data (404).

Comment: @YancyMelany I created a spreadsheet in my own Google Workspace and was able to reproduce using the same app and my own Workspace credentials. Same issue - yields a 404 Not Found when pointing my at own spreadsheet via GET request, but if I put the same URL into the OAuth Playground, I get a 200 OK.

Comment: this _' if I simply take the fresh access token from the Playground and drop that into Postman, I get the same 404'_ is very odd, I do the exact same and I am able to get a successful response whether the spreadsheet belongs to a gmail.com account or a Google Workspace one. I don't believe this has anything to do with the  project but I am using an already created one, let me try with a fresh one

Comment: After extensively testing on my end using the very same steps followed by you I am able to successfully get access to any Google Sheets owned by either a Gmail.com account or a Google Workspace account, this seems to be a localized issue to your environment so my best recommendation would be to get in touch with Google Workspace support via their [Developer Form](https://support.google.com/a/contact/wsdev) Be aware that as per their scope they will only be able to investigate why you are not able to query Google Sheets owned by your GW account via APIs

Comment: I have a new theory about why this is failing (because it's not just on my machine - I've reproduced in four different Azure environments now). I can't find a comprehensive list of the scopes Google deems sensitive or restricted, but is it perhaps the case that my unverified app (again, public, but testing), is being blocked at the actual resource call for relying on a sensitive scope (e.g. the broad spreadsheets.read) instead of the seemingly preferred drive.file? Presumably Google's apps would be approved and verified, mine would not - that's the only distinction I can find.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, you are right, Google has not provided an actual list of what scopes are considered sensitive or restricted, however as per [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#:~:text=Sensitive%20scopes%20require%20review%20by%20Google%20and%20have%20a%20sensitive%20indicator%20on%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20Platform%20(GCP)%20Console%27s%20OAuth%20consent%20screen%20configuration%20page) you could see it when adding the scope and spreadsheets.readonly [is sensitive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ydB.png)